# Android - Record Video and Set Video Size (Dimensions)

Tags: java, android, video, video-capture

I'm in the process of refactoring a piece of code that records videos (from the camera) ranging usually between 3 and 30 seconds in order to decrease the overall size (in bytes) of the video.

We were previously using `CamcorderProfile`, but it does not provide enough granularity for our application so I have now transitioned to manually adjusting all of the settings (audio source, video source, video frame rate, audio encoder, etc).

The issue is I cannot find a reliable method for selecting the optimal video size since there does not (to my knowledge) exist a universal list of sizes that all Android devices support. I would like the video to be as close to 480x360px as possible since we push our video to Amazon Elastic Transcoder, which makes the videos 480x360px in a variety of formats (mp4, webm, etc).

Below is a snippet of code of my general idea:

```
List<Camera.Size> sizes = camera.getParameters().getSupportedVideoSizes();
Camera.Size s;

//
// select size from sizes???
//

recorder = new MediaRecorder();
camera.stopPreview();
camera.unlock();
recorder.setCamera(camera);

// configure recorder
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);

recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

// WHAT IS THE SIZE??    
recorder.setVideoSize(s.width, s.height);

recorder.setVideoFrameRate(15);

recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
```

I have looked at a variety of posts on here as well as the Android Compatibility Definition Documents for 4.4 - 6.0.

Any ideas or resources are greatly appreciated.

Comment: screen recording or through the camera?

Comment: Through the camera, but the preview display is the screen

Comment: You should specify that in the question